# PHP method chaining

Tags: php, method-chaining

So i was wondering if there is a way to method chain, when the initial method is a static function. Here is what I mean:

```
    class foo
    {
        public static function a()
        {
            $foo = new foo;
            return $foo->bar(); 
        }

        public function bar()
        {
            return $this;
        }

        public function b()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    print foo::a()->b();
```

**EDIT**
`print foo::a()->b();` not `print foo:a()->b();`

Comment: You should not be getting an array anywhere with this code, I don't think this the actual code you're using. Besides, you are not calling function `bar()`, you are calling property `bar`. Demo of this working: http://codepad.org/5kPLusX8

Comment: That was just a typo on my end. And no, this is not the actual code. Just a conceptual question

Comment: There were a few typos, but that's not what I was referring to. In function `a()`, you aren't returning `bar()`, you are returning `bar`. Something in your testing is off, you should have taken the time to at least share the code you meant, or something that actually works to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: After adding the missing method call and semicolon (`$foo->bar();`) this code works for me and gives 1. What do you get?

Comment: Ay yes of coarse. Yah another dumb typo. Updated.

Comment: @Headspin: Did you actually test your updated code? [It should work fine](http://codepad.org/yaNUARfH).

Comment: Now it looks like if it would work. `foo::a()->bar()->bar()->b();` even if pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static Methods or Other Methods, as long as the method is **returning an object** either self or some other, the methods can be chained, with the same method you are attempting.

```
class foo {
   public function __construct() {
   }
   public function create() {
       // create something;
       return $this;
   }
   public function performSomethingElse() {
      // perform something
      return $this;
   }
}
$object = new foo;

$object -> create() -> performSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
print foo:a();
```

should be

```
print foo::a();
```

and you will not be able to return `$this` in a static method
it needs to be instantiated first:

```
$foo = new Foo();
print $foo->a()->b();
```

Comment: yes i see your update, there is a difference between `$foo->bar();` and `$foo::bar()`; in the second one you can't return $this. thats why i used `new Foo();`

Answer (score 0):

Only sort of an answer, and somewhat idiosyncratic:
But I would advise that you have your object accompanied by a *factory procedure* instead:

```
 class foo { .... }

 function foo() { return new foo; }
```

This might remove some of the confusion for you. And it even looks a bit nicer by avoiding the mix of static and object method calls:

```
 foo()->bar()->b();
```

It basically externalizes the static function. And your object only implements the chainable methods which return $this, or actual results.

Comment: That's the purpose of the separate function. It does instantiate a `new foo;`